# how to recover semi-corrupt data from working harddisk?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, data-recovery

In my 1 TB hard-disk very strange problem occurs. When I backup my Linux Data into another hard disk during copy process because of interrupted power supply or may be connection cable problem hard disk automatically unmount but that same time copying process was working. After that I reconnect HDD I face a problem in that problem 
1. my all previous data is OK. But a folder in which I coping my data is corrupt. and unable to open..
2. All previous folder data also non accessible but folder proper shows data size.
Other info. HDD file system is NTFS. HDD only works with linux and when I connect to Windows HDD unable to detect. 
Here is screen-shot of problem.
[image]

Comment: @karel thanks, but in my case, only that particular read/write problem occur, and other data is safe. also when i check property of that folder its shows actual size of that folder.  i just want to repair that read/write problem. obviously data recovery is ultimate solution for that problem. but its better if any chechdisk operation can solve it, coz its save time.

Comment: If the disk remounts as read-only due to hardware, then remount it again as read-write and try the operation again. But that's a temporary bandage over a deep wound *if you have untrustworthy hardware*. Ubuntu is designed to work on properly functioning hardware. From your description, your data does not seem safe.